# How to configure PuTTY's screen size and quality from a Target link address?

Tags: windows-10, putty

I know I can create an auto login to my host server by creating a shortcut to PuTTY and in the Target field under the Shortcut tab have

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh username@11.222.333.444"`

[image]

Problem is, my font appears to fuzzy under Windows 10, and I found an answer that suggested to change the Window Appearance font Quality to "Antialiased".

[image]

Question is, how can I configure the shortcut link itself to open up with the configurations I want? What configurations are allowed to be included in the `Target` address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Putty Configuration Panel, set the appearance that you'd like, such as the Font Quality and possibly other settings you'd like to have preconfigured.

Then, under "Session" save this session under a name, for example "Antialiased".

Change your Putty command line to:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "Antialiased" -ssh username@11.222.333.444`

Putty will now load with the settings you preconfigured under the session name.

Comment: I have looked into how to do the same thing for the font, and seen this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/52068/is-there-a-way-to-permanently-set-the-font-and-window-size-in-putty I edited the Default Settings and it loaded the older settings. Having  `-load "Antialiased"` will override the default settings. I removed it and the default settings took over. Is there a way to load specific font and font size from the Target link?

Comment: You can include any setting you want (including font, size, color, terminal settings etc) in a stored session. You can only load them as part of a stored session (including all other settings that were stored in that session), which will override any default settings with the ones stored in your session. AFAIK there is no way to specify font and font size directly as part of a target link or on the command line. Does that answer your question?